# Generate Agent Job Report

Tags: sql-server

We have a few jobs that run nightly that the status has to be reported every hour.  I am trying to find in MSDB where I can capture the information below hourly and send out an excel file.

```
Server          Job Order - Name        NormalStartTime NormalEndTime   ActualStartTime ActualEndTime
Server A        1. JobA     11:00:00 PM     11:05:00 PM     11:00:00 PM     11:06:15 PM
Server A        2. JobB     11:05:00 PM     11:15:00 PM     11:06:16 PM     11:31:09 PM
Server A        3. JobC     11:15:00 PM     11:45:00 PM     11:31:09 PM     12:52:04 AM
Server A        4. JobD     11:45:00 PM     11:50:00 PM     12:52:04 AM     12:53:08 AM
Server A        5. JobE     11:50:00 PM     12:00:00 AM     12:53:09 AM     12:56:59 AM
```

Server = Server Name
Job Order - Name = This is the list of Jobs I want to search for.  The 1-5 is not in the job name.
NormalStartTime = Earliest Start time
NormalEndTime = Latest End Time
ActualStartTime = The time the job started on today's run
ActualEndTime = The time the job finished today's run

Comment: If today's End Time was the latest end time, would you want that to show in the NormalEndTime field?

For your information, the data is in the msdb sys tables. Give it a go yourself and come back if you need help
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174997.aspx

Comment: Try `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory` and go from there

Comment: Be aware that SQL Server will only retain a limited amount of job history.  This can be set in Agent -> Properties -> history.  If you have a lot of job activity history may be purged before you get to report on it.  Specifically your "Normal" columns may not have the accuracy you think they should.  It may be necessary to copy job history to your own DB at frequent intervals rather than rely on MSDB.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the script as per your need

> ```
> SELECT h.SERVER AS [Server Name]
>   ,j.NAME AS [Job Name]
>   ,CONVERT(TIME, a.start_execution_date) AS [Normal Start Time]
>   ,CONVERT(TIME, a.last_executed_step_date) AS [Normal End Time]
>   ,CONVERT(TIME, a.run_requested_date) AS [Actual Start Time]
>   ,CONVERT(TIME, a.stop_execution_date) AS [Actual End Time]
>   ,h.run_time
> FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS h
> INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j ON h.job_id = j.job_id
> INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity AS a ON h.job_id = a.job_id
> WHERE h.run_date = (
>       SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)
>       )
>   AND H.run_time >= (
>       SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(TIME(0), CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(HOUR, - 1, GETDATE()))), '.', ''), ':', '')
>       )
>   AND h.step_id = 1
>   AND a.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
>   AND a.last_executed_step_date IS NOT NULL
>   AND a.run_requested_date IS NOT NULL
>   AND a.stop_execution_date IS NOT NULL
> ```